# Loop through infinitely nested object & Construct string

Tags: javascript, loops, object, recursion

I'm using [this query component](https://sapientglobalmarkets.github.io/react-querybuilder/) in one of my projects so that users can construct a query.

I'm having difficulty parsing it into an actual example query, for example for this object outputted by the component:

```
const queryParams = {
  "rules": [
    {
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "firstName",
          "value": "John",
          "operator": "="
        },
        {
          "field": "lastName",
          "value": "Doe",
          "operator": "="
        }
      ],
      "combinator": "and"
    },
    {
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "age",
          "value": "20",
          "operator": "="
        },
        {
          "field": "address",
          "value": "London",
          "operator": "="
        }
      ],
      "combinator": "and"
    }
  ],
  "combinator": "and"
}
```

I need to create a function that would output a more user-friendly readable output as such:

```
((FirstName = John AND LastName = Doe) AND (AGE = 20 AND Address = London))
```

I've given it a go but the difficulty I'm finding is that:

- The object could theoretically be infinitely nested, I never know how nested it is. Is the only way to do this with recursion? Or are there easier ways
- The rules and groups can be in the same object

The way I'm currently trying will not work dynamically, so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you share how you are currently trying to do it?

Comment: "object could theoretically be infinitely nested" - using for loop should overcome this issue, did you try any recursions? Share your code

Comment: You can always use a loop and a stack (LIFO) structure to simulate recursion if you decide to go that way. This (non-JS) explanation is pretty straightforward: https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html ... (although if you want to get into that wacky recursion stuff, this seems like a great JS tutorial: https://javascript.info/recursion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach and build either a rules set or a final comparison.

It works by checking the `rules` property:

- If given, then the `rules` are mapped with a recursive call of the function.

  The result of this call is joined with an upper case `combinator` property and wrapped into a wanted spaced string with parenthesis.
- If not, then take a new string with `field`, `operator` and `value` property.

```js
function combine(object) {
    return 'rules' in object
        ? `(${object.rules.map(combine).join(` ${object.combinator.toUpperCase()} `)})`
        : `${object.field} ${object.operator} ${object.value}`;
}

var data = { rules: [{ rules: [{ field: "firstName", value: "John", operator: "=" }, { field: "lastName", value: "Doe", operator: "=" }], combinator: "and" }, { rules: [{ field: "age", value: "20", operator: "=" }, { field: "address", value: "London", operator: "=" }], combinator: "and" }], combinator: "and" },
    result = combine(data);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Really nice approach, but it would be better with an explanation. ;)

Comment: This is really a dump component, its missing the field type :) so we could identify if the field is string, int etc

Comment: @Alen.Toma, i think it's just to visualise to the user in a simplified style what's happening.

Comment: Correct @NinaScholz - Thank you for the solution this is great